# Combining Multiple Guards in Boost Metastate Machine

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a way to combine multiple guards in the functor front end for boost meta state machine?

I'd like to do the following:

```
struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
//    Start     Event        Target      Action                      Guard 
//   +---------+------------+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+ 
Row  < Stopped , play       ,  Playing  , start_playback            , guard1 && guard2              >          
//   +---------+------------+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+ 
> {};
```

`guard1` and `guard2` are both boolean expressions. This however does not compile. Boost SML allows this easily.

with the following code:

```
struct actions_guards {
  auto operator()() noexcept {
    using namespace sml;
    return make_transition_table(
       *"idle"_s + event<e1> = "s1"_s
      , "s1"_s + event<e2> [ guard1 && guard2 ] / action1 = X
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <boost/msm/front/euml/euml.hpp>
using namespace euml;

struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
//    Start     Event        Target      Action                      Guard 
//   +---------+------------+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+ 
Row  < Stopped , play       ,  Playing  , start_playback            , And_<guard1, guard2>              >          
//   +---------+------------+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+ 
> {};
```